# Why is FindBugs complaining here?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, findbugs

```
 public int getFreezeColumns() {
    Integer currentValue = (Integer) checkValueBinding("freezeColumns", this.freezeColumns);
    if (currentValue != null) {
      return currentValue;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

FindBugs says :

> A primitive is boxed, and then immediately unboxed. This probably is due to a manual boxing in a place where an unboxed value is required, thus forcing the compiler to immediately undo the work of the boxing.

How can I possibly fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the complaint is somewhat misleading: you are not boxing the return value of `checkValueBinding` which is an `Object`, but you are casting it to `Integer` prematurely

Try changing the code to see if it helps you avoid the warning:

```
public int getFreezeColumns() {
    Object currentValue = checkValueBinding("freezeColumns", this.freezeColumns);
    if (currentValue != null) {
        return (Integer)currentValue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like it's complaining that you are creating an `Integer`, and then converting it to `int` right away to return it.

What does checkValueBinding return? Do you really need to wrap it into an `Integer`?

Comment: `checkValueBinding` returns Object , hence the cast .

Comment: Try returning currentValue.intValue(). Either way it doesn't look like there's a huge issue here. The tool seems to think you are converting to Integer needlessly and then back to int immediately.